# WinAPI/MFC User-defined functions

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a simple C++ console application I use to drive a colorimeter.
The functions that interface to the device were provided in the form of a MSVC DLL with `__cdecl` functions.

I was also given the corresponding `.h` and `.lib` files. All processing rests on an Event handler that needs to be instantiated on startup. It is called from within the DLL functions to alert when data is ready for retrieval. The device is connected to the USB port and appears as a (virtual?) COM port in Device Manager (COM0).

I need to "port" this simple application to a GUI environment to sustain my project. I tried QT Creator 5.15.2 (with MinGW Open Source option) and Embarcadero C++Builder, but getting access from these environments to the DLL functions is impossible. I experimented with wxWidget, but it "did not work" for me -- I could not get the Sample to execute, for some reason (couldn't find "Main/Invoke"?).

So I turned my attention to MFC and WinAPI. Creating a C++ MFC app is "straight forward" up to the point that I have to figure "how to interface" my device to this system. I tried creating a custom class, `myDevice`, to regroup all my custom functions such as "Connect" and "Calibrate" and "Measure".

In `main.h`, I declare this class:

```
class myDevice{
private:
   //bool CalibratedStatus;
public:
   bool Connect();
   bool Calibrate();
   bool Measure();
   myDevice();
   ~myDevice();
};
```

Then in `Main.cpp`, I have the member functions definitions:

```
MainApp::MainApp()
{
    // TODO: add construction code here,
    DEVICE_ERROR_TYPES deviceError = DEVICE_RegisterDeviceEventHandler(EventNotice);

    // Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
}

myDevice::MyDEVICE() { }
myDevice::~MyDEVICE() { }

bool myDevice::Connect() {

    string StatusDEVICE;
    uint8 StateTableRB, portInfoName, portInfoSerialNo;
    string DevicePortList;
    uint32 portCount = 0;
    DEVICE_PortInfo portInfo[16];
    uint8 StateTable[2][4] = { "Eth", "USB" };

    // "01 Looking for the instrument...
    DEVICE_GetDevicePortList(0, &portCount, 0);

    if (portCount > 16) {
        portCount = 16;
    }
    else if (portCount < 1) {
        // printf("device not found\n");
       return false;
    }

    DEVICE_GetDevicePortList(portInfo, &portCount, portCount);  // display device list

    deviceError = DEVICE_Connect(&portInfo[0], 10);

    if (DEVICE_SUCCESSFUL(deviceError)) {
        StatusDEVICE = "Device Connect Complete!";
        // printf("Device Connect Complete!\n");
        return true;
    }
}

bool myDevice::Calibrate() { }

bool myDevice::Measure() {

    if (CalibratedStatus == true) {

        // Set measure condition
        DEVICE_MeasureCondition measureCondition = { measureType, 0 };
        deviceError = DEVICE_SetMeasureCondition(&measureCondition);
        // start measurement
        deviceError = DEVICE_StartMeasurement();

        if (device_SUCCESSFUL(deviceError)) {
           while (!isMeasureWait) {
               if (isDisConnect) break; 
               // waiting for measurement complete
                  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
           }
           ExportMeasureData(measureType);
           isMeasureWait = true;
           return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Then I need to use these flags:

```
bool isMeasureCompleted = false;
bool isCcalibrationCompleted = false;
bool isCcalibrationFailed = false;
bool isMeasureWait = false;
```

Which I place above the `MainApp::MainApp()` line (Globals?).

I'll admit I don't have any experience coding for MFC or WinAPI, but I have a hunch it's radically different from declaring an Event handler somewhere in the middle of a source file and followed by a bunch of loose functions that retrieve data.

Somehow, it is not clear to me WHERE can 'user-defined functions" like these 'strategically' be placed? And called? If I create a button, let's say, to 'Connect' to the Device, in the button handler, it's easy to place the code that connects to the device and execute it from there. But what about the "Return"? Because the return is not 'direct' (maybe it's 'asynchronous'?); the return always takes the route of the Event Handler and lands in the Event Notice that's where I have a Switch statement that redirects the task to the function that correspond to the "Event received". I cannot change that behavior.

I was reading about Serial communications applications that, from what I understand, use "Serial Events" from within MFC, to trigger calls to the functions? But that's really 'new' to me. I'm not sure whether this would be a good approach? As you can see in the code above, there is a 'thread sleep' that executes "while the device" is busy? Once the device is done, it calls the Event Notice handler on its own with its response:

```
void EventNotice(DEVICE_EventCode outEventCode, uint32 outRAWDataCount, DEVICE_ERROR_TYPES outError)
{
       switch (outEventCode) {
         case Event_Standby:        // 0
            // cout << "Standby..." << endl;
             break;
         case Event_MeasureWait:        // 1
            if (isMeasureCompleted) {
               // export measure data
               // printf("\n04 Export Measure Data...");
               ExportMeasureData(measureType);          
               isMeasureWait = true;
         case ...
```

I need to be able to implement this Event Handler function as is? Otherwise, I don't have access to the device.

That's where I'm not sure how this can be done in a "Message processing" approach: I can't just "dump" the Event handler code anywhere and expect the device to find the Event handler by magic, on its own, right? It does not work like in a simple procedural program, does it?

I've been reading a lot about how to transpose my silly console application code to MFC/WinAPI, but all I find are references to how to *use* the API itself, how to create buttons and menus and resources, but nothing like what I'm trying to accomplish.

==== Update 2021 04 14

@Remy: I moved the DLL function calls out of my class and now getting a different kind of error from the Linker. Before, the error referred to
"public: __thiscall" ...., now, the error refers to
"public: __cdecl".

I read this morning that c++ functions were always prefixed with "__thiscall"?
I got rid the of the __thiscall prefix but but the Linker is still unable to find the functions. with the __cdel prefix. BTW, I would *love* to embark on this project with C++ Builder!! I tried using IMPLIB and COFF2OMF and then IMPDEF but was not successful to coerce the DLL to work with C++ Builder to no avail.
From the documentation: C++Builder cannot use .lib files from other compilers, only its own. If the .lib file is an import lib for a DLL, use C++Builder's command-line IMPLIB tool to create a new .lib file from the DLL directly. Which is what I did (to the best of my ability).
In the end, I used this statement in my Source file to direct the compiler to my new .lib version : #pragma comment(lib, "FDXSDK.lib")

Here are the first four lines of the EDF I got from IMDEF :

LIBRARY     DEVICE.DLL
EXPORTS
DEVICE_CalculateMeasureData       @60  ; DEVICE_CalculateMeasureData
DEVICE_Calibration                @61  ; DEVICE_Calibration

I tried contacting Embarcadero support but since I'm only using the 'Community' edition, there is no support -- forget about the Forum. I search every reference I could and tried everything I could before giving up.

At the end of the day, I'm still getting "Unresolved Reference" from Embarcadero Linker.

=== UPDATE 2  / 2021 04 15 ================
I looked at Dumpbin utility to check on the function names inside the DLL and got this output (only showing the first lines):

dumpbin DEVICE.dll /EXPORTS
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.28.29913.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file device.dll

File Type: DLL

Section contains the following exports for DEVICE.dll

```
00000000 characteristics
FFFFFFFF time date stamp
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
      91 number of functions
      91 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

     60    0 0003E2F0 DEVICE_Calculate
     61    1 0003DA60 DEVICE_Calibrate
     62    2 0003DE10 DEVICE_Cancel
     63    3 0003D7D0 DEVICE_Connect
     64    4 0003D8E0 DEVICE_Disconnect
```

Comment: Sorry I can't make it clear what your problem is, Could you please show [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without private information?

Comment: Basically, I wonder how to go from a procedural programming approach to a message-based approach? I'll try to dig out some error messages...

Comment: OK, when I run the code, I get this LINK2019 Unresolved external symbol :
_DEVICE_RegisterDeviceEventHandler@4 referenced in function "public: __thiscall CMainApp::CMainApp(void)" (??0CMainApp@@QAE@XZ)

I suspect the Linker cannot find my device DLL functions? Presumably (I am no expert) because of the 'wrong' calling convention, as I see, for some reason, the Linker is expecting the __thiscall 'prefix' when all the DLL functions are prefixed with __cdecl?

Otherwise, the gist of my question was "Am I approaching the problem from a good angle"?

Comment: That error is saying the linker can't find the `DEVICE_RegisterDeviceEventHandler()` function that your own code is calling from inside of `CMainApp::CMainApp()`. Sounds like you didn't include the DLL's `.lib` import file in your project, or it is not compatible with your build tools.

Comment: Also, "*I tried ... Embarcadero C++Builder, but getting access ... to the DLL functions is impossible*" - I find that hard to believe. Especially if the DLL is designed with a C interface, as this appears to be. It should work in *any* C/C++ compiler, including C++Builder. I have used many many C-based DLLs in C++Builder over the years, they work just fine. Sometimes (usually), I just need to generate a new import lib using  C++Builder's `IMPLIB` or `MKEXP` tool, as most DLL vendors don't provide `.lib` files for C++Builder. Sometimes (rarely), I have to make tweaks to a DLL's `.h` files.

Comment: There is nothing "magic" in calling the event handler. You specified the function address in the `DEVICE_RegisterDeviceEventHandler()` call, so the library knows which function to send the events to. In response to these events you can update the user-interface and/or store the data received. Check the library's documentation, if these events arrive asynchronously (although I guess you can figure this out, from the application's behavior).

Comment: Also, as noted by Remy above, you have to include the `.lib` file in your project and check if it builds. These are called "import libraries" and contain minimal code, which just calls the DLL functions, while providing functions that can be statically linked to your code. If the import library doesn't link, you can use the `LoadLibrary()/GetProcAddress()` functions, as a last resort. And yes,sometimes such problems can be caused by wrong declarations in header files, eg ansi-wide char args or C++ "decorations". Check the function name in the DLL and your linker.Also check the "C" delcaration.

Comment: What I see you are not using MFC. MainApp::MainApp() This is C# style

Comment: @Constantine: I tried LoadLibrary("Device.dll") but it always returns NULL (I made sure the DLL could be found by placing a copy in System32). But I should not have to work that hard? The DLL links perfectly inside a simple Console Application. Why can't it be found inside a GUI (MFC/WinAPI/Qt/C++Builder) app is a mystery to me.

Comment: Try to use an absolute path and use `GetLastError` to check the specific cause of the error.

Comment: A DLL doesn't necessarily need to lie in the System32 folder in order to be loaded. It can be in the same folder as the executable (do this if you want the DLL to be available only to your app), the current folder (but better don't rely on this), or any folder included in the PATH environment variable. Imo it is worth trying `LoadLibrary()`. As noted above, the `GetLastError()` function will tell you why the load why the loading fails. It can be anything, including a 32/64-bit mismatch. Also, the application type (console or GUI) is irrelevant.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by the DLL "can't be found in a GUI app". Again, what you need inside your app is the `.lib` file. Does it link successfully or not? If not, check the error-code. If it does, the DLL **should** be loading. The reason why you can't match the lib with the dll names is probably because the ones in the DLL are not decorated. Try using the `"C"` declaration, a `#pragma comment(linker, ..)` directive or a module definition file, to strip the decoration stuff off the names.